# Intercepting any request - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have a web page say - `sample-page.html` with 2 links in it -

> sample-page.html
>        - link1 (GET, ajax)
>        - link 2 (GET, new page)

When I click `link1` an ajax `GET` request is executed and it still stays at the sample-`page.html`.When I click `link2` another get request is executed and a new page `sample-page2`  will appear.

To intercept both requests I've written a javascript code like this -

```
    //attempt-1 : javascript
    (function (send) {

        XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function () {
            this.setRequestHeader('some-header-param', 'some-value');
            send.apply(this, arguments);
        };

    })(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send);

    //attempt-2: jquery 
    /*$.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function (xhr,settings) {
           xhr.setRequestHeader('some-header', 'some-header-value');
       }
      }); */
```

The above, both attempts successfully able to intercept the ajax GET request from `link1`.
But neither of the above code snippets can't able to intercept the request from `link2`. Can anyone help how to intercept both requests?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by using javascript event.preventDefault() functionality.
Write a event listener for onclick on that  element. Do whatever functionality you want and call event.preventDefault() if you want stop sending the request otherwise leave it as it is.

```
<a id='some_id'>click here</a>

document.getElementById('some_id').addEventListener('click',function(event){
    //do whatever you want.
    //If you want to stop the request.
    if(need_to_stop){
        event.preventDefault();
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

When doing an AJAX call, you're in complete control of the request. But when you click a link that goes to another URL entirely, there is not much you can do. You might want to look into the [`beforeunload` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event). With that event, you can cancel it in order to show a popup dialog asking if the user wants to navigate away or not.

Answer (score 1):

you add custome attribute to the a tags that you want to intercept (eg: data-intercept)

```
<a href="\\google.com" data-intercept="true">google</a>
```

**Jquery**

```
 $(document).on('click','a[data-intercept="true"]',function(e){e.preventDefault(); alert();});
```

jquery will only intercept the a tag clicks that has attribute data-intercept ="true"

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you have to either watch for a click event (preferably) on the link or monitor for unload event. A user clicking a html link has nothing to do with AJAX or Jquery except for the clicking part which is a DOM event. If you decide to use beforeunload, you have to return an [undefined value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) to prevent a prompt.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    //do stuff
    return undefined;
}
```